# How do I print out every other key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Given:

```
d = {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
sorted_dict = d.keys()
sorted_dict = sorted(sorted_dict)

for key in sorted_dict:
    print(key)
```

How do I make it so that it outputs every other key. Right now it outputs:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

but I want it to output:

```
a
c
e
```

Comment: It might be clearer and more minimal to only mention `d` in the question, not `sorted_dict`, which is a different issue.

Comment: yea but I need it to be sorted as well which I figured out but now I have to make it so it outputs every other key from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python provides "slicing" for very powerful and elegant solutions to problems like this. It's too big a topic to fully explain here but lot's of information all over the net on this core topic, here's a suggestion:
https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-slicing/

To solve your specific problem:

```
d = {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
sorted_dict = d.keys()
sorted_dict = sorted(sorted_dict)

for key in sorted_dict[::2]:
    print(key)
```

The [::2] here specifies that you want to take all of the sorted list from start to finish but in steps of 2 (ie. every other element)

Incidentally, you can dispense with the for loop and just print your list slice!..

```
d = {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
sorted_dict = d.keys()
sorted_dict = sorted(sorted_dict)

print(sorted_dict[::2])

['a', 'c', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `d` be the dictionary to print alternating rows on.

```
d = {'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
d = dict(sorted(d.items()))
```

Dictionaries are sequences, just like lists. Similar techniques can be used for both to keep alternating entries:

```
for i, key in enumerate(d.keys()):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(key)
```

Or:

```
for key in list(d.keys())[::2]:
    print(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_dict = d.keys()
sorted_dict = sorted(sorted_dict)
for key in range(0, len(sorted_dict),2): print(key)
```

Comment: This doesn't output anything

Comment: The two-argument version of `range` interprets the arguments as the start and end points, not the end and a stride length. You need to use the three-argument version with an explicit starting point of 0: range(0, len(sorted_dict), 2)`.